# Does mysqlslap measure network performance?

Tags: mysql, load, database-performance, amazon-aurora

I'm using [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlslap.html) to load test an aurora database.

Does mysqlslap consider network latency when it times queries?

It doesn't appear to be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I suspect that it does not separate out network performance.  However, the network may be the limiting factor, since mysqlslap is using lots of connections to run lots of queries each.

Comment: Beware of any benchmark tool; it rarely simulates _your_ application.

Comment: Run something trivial like `SELECT 1;`  If it says minimum 32ms, then the latency between client ans server is about 32ms.